# How to work with dates and calendar in Ruby on Rails to create trips and routes every day?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Started learning Ruby on Rails, I want to create a website online ticket sale.

For example:

- https://busfor.com/
- http://www.easybook.com/

How to work with dates and calendar in Ruby on Rails (so as not to create every day new flights and routes every day if he repeats).

I would be grateful for feedback

Comment: Do you mean just date input fields?

Comment: Creating a route or flight in dashboard, the client will be able to select a date and choose a route. How to do so in dashboard to create a one-time route, not to duplicate it every day manually. I don't understand how to work with this calendar.

Comment: What you ask is 'setup an architecture for my application`. I've provide you link for rails datepicker. Everything else goes beyond simple stackoverflow question

Comment: The customer selects the date which is 3 months, another after 2 weeks, 3 wants for tomorrow, they just show Flights, because flights take place every day, changing only the date. I can something I say is not correct, then correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a datepicker for rails -- https://github.com/benignware/date_picker